# Corda Serialization Whitelist

Tags: serialization, blockchain, corda

I was trying to serialized a class (DTO) to be used in send and receive
in flows.My DTO class is not in the same module as flows.  I
am getting the below errors

1.With @CordaSerializable annotation , My DTO class is not getting serialized and it is throwing

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: Class "class com.e_mobility.dto.dashboard.DashboardDTO" is not on the whitelist or annotated with @CordaSerializable
```

2. With manual whitelisting like below

   class CustomSerializationWhiteList : SerializationWhitelist {
   override val whitelist: List<Class<*>> = listOf(DTO::class.java)
   }

I am getting this error during runtime

```
 net.corda.core.serialization.internal.MissingSerializerException: Unable to create an object serializer for type class com.e_mobility.dto.dashboard.DashboardDTO:
Mandatory constructor parameters [arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6] are missing from the readable properties []
Either provide getters or readable fields for [arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6], or provide a custom serializer for this type
```

Please help me to resolve this error. (edited)

Answer (score 0):

As you are creating a custom type, did you check that all the needed requirements are fulfilled in your class? The annotation alone might be not enough. From the related [Corda documentation](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/serialization.html#custom-types) about serialization with custom types:

> - The class must be compiled with parameter names included in the .class file. This is the default in Kotlin but must be turned on in
>   Java using the -parameters command line option to javac
> - The class must be annotated with @CordaSerializable
> - The declared types of constructor arguments, getters, and setters must be supported, and where generics are used, the generic parameter
>   must be a supported type, an open wildcard (*), or a bounded wildcard
>   which is currently widened to an open wildcard
> - Any superclass must adhere to the same rules, but can be abstract
> - Object graph cycles are not supported, so an object cannot refer to itself, directly or indirectly